# Onclick function on dynamically created span

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, i found many "solutions" that aren't working anymore, so I started a topic again.
`var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = name + "<br>";
    span.id = name;
    span.className = "filelist";
    span.onclick = function(){
    $(this).hide();
    };`
Somehow, the onclick part is not working when i create span element.
I really have no idea now, how to make it work, as similar solutions doesnt work neither.
Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nX67s/)

Comment: Are you using jquery or not? Is $() defined?

Comment: 1. Please use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to create **runnable** examples right here on-site. 2. Your fiddle doesn't do what the code in your question does (which is one reason for using Stack Snippets instead).

Comment: There's a typo in your code: `onlick` instead of `onclick`.

Comment: seems that you are using native javscript alone then you use jquery function at the end.

Comment: in the fiddle you forgot the c in onclick.

Comment: OK yeah there was a typo and jsfiddle works now but still, if i do same for span, its not working... Tried to hange to ``span.onclick = function() { $(this).find('span').hide(); };`` and its not working neither...

Comment: @se7en if you just want to hide the span after you created it you can do ```del.onclick = function () {
    alert("hi  jaavscript");
    del.style.display = 'none';
};```

Comment: `$(this).find('span').hide();` - `this` IS a span, and `find` tries to find elements among its children, and fails as expected. `$(this).hide()` should be enough (if jQuery is imported correctly of course). Notice how far away your original question gets from the real one. Do you really think it'll be helpful to anyone but you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var name = "some";
   
var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
    span.innerHTML = name + "<br>";
    span.id = name;
    span.className = "filelist";
    span.onclick = function(){
    $(this).hide();
    };
    document.body.appendChild(span);
```

```css
.filelist
{
  color:green;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry but the jsfiddle example was about the "similar answers". please make it work for my current code which uses span.

Comment: Yeahthis really seem to work, i needed to upgrade my jquery from 2.0.4 to 2.1.1, which is pretty funny lol

Comment: Just curious now if this is good place to ask another related question: before the ``var span =...`` i had ``data.name.push(name);``, but now when i want to remove this in onclick function: ``data.name = data.name.splice(data.name.indexOf(this.id));`` it doesnt seem to work ;(

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `$(this)` exists when you're trying to click it. Console log it and see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

> Use the following code snippet
>   **element.addEventListener("click",EVNT_FUNCTION);**

```
 var del = document.createElement('input');
 del.type = 'button';
 del.name = 'delll';
 del.value = 'del';

 // define the event and add to the element
 del.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
 function myFunction() {
   // your event codes here
    alert("hi  jaavscript");
 };
 document.body.appendChild(del);
```

I hope you can understand this. Or comment it please